# How to filter based on a start and end date where the dates can be null

Tags: directus

I am able to filter if the date field is null or I can filter if the date field is older than now. But, I cannot combine them, nor am I able to do this or grouping for both fields.

Is there a way to group filters?
Is there a way to check if the date is null, I want all nulls OR if the date is prior to now.

This does not work:

```
&filter[publish_on][lte]=now&filter[publish_on][logical]=[or]&filter[publish_on][null]
```